# @1x size of image assets in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image

When adding images to an iOS project, what size should the 1x image be?

For example:

If I have 2 `UIImageView` with the same image with a size of 50x50pt and 30x30pt. Can I make one image asset for the both (and which size should this be) or should I make 2 assets ie. image30x30.png and image50x50.png?

This of course extends to images that have a dynamic size (for example 50% of the screen width), which size should they be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use 1 image and just resize UIImageView
2. Yes, you should use 2 different assets if 1. won't work for you

Comment: When you don't believe the quality of how it's going to be resized. Sometimes you don't want to use any scales, and just set view.contentMode = .Center so you are sure it looks just as you image does

Comment: Just get 1 asset that is big enough to cover all the situations and resize it down where you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to resize an image you must remember 2 things:

1. you must maintain the h/w ratio of that image.
2. you must resize to smaller from it's original size otherwise the resized image will look blur .

So, according to your (50x50pt and 30x30pt)images size the best option is to maintain 1 image and it size must be 50x50pt

i) resize this image smaller into 30x30pt

ii) you should not consider image ratio as both image maintain same ratio.(50/50=1 and 30/30 =1)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use 2 different image assets for your `UIImageView`.

Comment: And how would this work for images that are constrained to, for example, 1/3 of the screen width? They would have a different size on different devices so which size should I make the asset?